# Probability of observing a likelihood function given model

Tags: distributions, maximum-likelihood

I have the data on the empirically estimated discrete likelihood functions (probability mass functions), and I want to do some model fitting (testing whether they match different distribution functions) on them. How can I compute a likelihood of the observed discrete likelihood function given a model?

Here's some simulated data:

```r
# generate simulated response from 8 channels
expo = 5
nchan = 8
centres = seq(0,(2*pi-0.001), by = (2*pi/nchan))
weights <- runif(nchan)

# let's make response concentrated on one channel
weights[3] <- 5

weights <- weights/sum(weights)

# functions to get the channel response
chan_resp <- function (x, c ){
  delta_pos(cos(x-centres[c]))^expo
}
delta_pos <- function (x){
  x[x<0] = 0
  x
}

x = seq(0,2*pi,length.out = 100)

response <- sapply(1:nchan, function (c) sapply(x, 
      function (xval) weights[c]*chan_resp(xval,c)))

response <- rowSums(response)/sum(response)

# check that the response is a p.m.f.
(sum(response)-1) < 1e-5

plot(x, response,'l')
```

So here's an example function:

[image: example function]

I want to test if it actually a Gaussian distribution, as opposed to, say, t-distribution. But how to compute the likelihood that it is a Gaussian or a t-distribution?

Comment: What is the difference between the likelihood of the sample and the likelihood of the empirical cdf?

Comment: are you suggesting to take a sample from that empirical CDF? but then to compare models with different number of parameters with, say, BIC, I need to know the sample size and here I can take a sample of any size